# How to bulkTransfer() read from USB_DIR_OUT?

Tags: android, usb, synchronous, serial-communication

My USB device has both IN and OUT `UsbEndpoint`s, but communicates **only on the OUT** endpoint. I send a message to it and device responds on the same endpoint.

I need to communicate synchronously, so that means using `bulkTransfer()`, right? `bulkTransfer()` determines direction by `UsbEndpoint.getDirection()` which cannot be changed. How should I use `bulkTransfer()` to **read** from the endpoint with OUT direction?

Comment: i guess i am facing the same problem

Comment: @AlexSales Unfortunately I still haven't solved it.